# How do I convert an int to a zero padded string in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's say I have an int with the value of 1. How can I convert that int to a zero padded string, such as `00000001`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
Declare @MyInt integer Set @MyInt = 123
Declare @StrLen TinyInt Set @StrLen = 8

Select Replace(Str(@MyInt, @StrLen), ' ' , '0')
```

Comment: Or on the fly if fixed lengths are given: `SELECT REPLACE(STR(DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]),2),' ','0')`

Answer (score 36):

as of SQL Server 2012 you can now do this:

```
format(@int, '0000#')
```

Comment: Succinct solution for sucky int :)

Comment: Performance is dreadful though.  In my sample of 300000 rows, FORMAT was ten times slower than REPLACE(STR(

Answer (score 35):

Another way is:

```
DECLARE @iVal int = 1
select REPLACE(STR(@iVal, 8, 0), ' ', '0')
```

Comment: I did and it works I was more asking how these functions work together, maybe the question is why there isn't a built in method for it

Comment: To just leave leading spaces, remove the Replace, e.g. select STR(@iVal, 8, 0)

Answer (score 11):

Use `FORMAT(<your number>,'00000000')` use as many zeroes as you need to have digits in your final outcome.

[Here is official documentation of the FORMAT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 9):

This work for me:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(Table.Field AS VARCHAR(3)),3) FROM Table
```

...

I created this user function

T-SQL Code :

```
CREATE FUNCTION CIntToChar(@intVal Int, @intLen Int) RETURNS nvarchar(24) AS BEGIN

IF @intlen > 24
   SET @intlen = 24

RETURN REPLICATE('0',@intLen-LEN(RTRIM(CONVERT(nvarchar(24),@intVal)))) 
    + CONVERT(nvarchar(24),@intVal) END
```

Example :

SELECT dbo.CIntToChar( 867, 6 ) AS COD_ID

OUTPUT

000867

Answer (score 1):

If I'm trying to pad to a specific total length, I use the REPLICATE and DATALENGTH functions, like so:

```
DECLARE @INT INT
DECLARE @UNPADDED VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @PADDED VARCHAR(3)

SET @INT = 2
SET @UNPADDED = CONVERT(VARCHAR(3),@INT)
SET @PADDED = REPLICATE('0', 3 - DATALENGTH(@UNPADDED)) + @UNPADDED
SELECT @INT, @UNPADDED, @PADDED
```

I used variables here for simplicity, but you see, you can specify the final length of the total string and not worry about the size of the INT that you start with as long as it's <= the final string length.

Answer (score 1):

I always use:

```
SET @padded = RIGHT('z0000000000000'
  + convert(varchar(30), @myInt), 8)
```

The z stops SQL from implicitly coverting the string into an int for the addition/concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

If the int can go negative you have a problem, so to get around this I sometimes do this:

```
DECLARE @iVal int 
set @iVal = -1
    select 
        case 
            when @ival >= 0 then right(replicate('0',8) + cast(@ival as nvarchar(8)),8)
            else '-' + right(replicate('0',8) + cast(@ival*-1 as nvarchar(8)),8)
        end
```

Comment: Thanks for catching this edge case.

Answer (score 1):

And then there's this one, using REPLICATE:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 7) + '1'
```

Of course, you can replace the literals 7 and '1' with appropriate functions as needed; the above gives you your example.  For example:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar, @myInt))) + CONVERT(nvarchar, @myInt)
```

will pad an integer of less than 8 places with zeros up to 8 characters.

Now, a negative number in the second argument of REPLICATE will return NULL.  So, if that's a possibility (say, @myInt could be over 100 million in the above example), then you can use COALESCE to return the number without leading zeros if there are more than 8 characters:

```
SELECT COALESCE(REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar, @myInt))) + CONVERT(nvarchar, @myInt), CONVERT(nvarchar, @myInt))
```

Answer (score 1):

Very straight forward way to think about padding with '0's is, if you fixed your @_int's to have 4 decimals, you inject 4 '0's:

```
    select RIGHT( '0000'+ Convert(varchar, @_int), 4) as txtnum
```

; if your fixed space is 3, you inject 3'0's

```
    select RIGHT( '000'+ Convert(varchar, @_int), 3) as txtnum
```

; below I inject '00' to generate 99 labels for each bldg

```
declare @_int int
set @_int = 1
while @_int < 100 Begin
    select BldgName + '.Floor_' + RIGHT( '00'+ Convert(varchar, @_int), 2) 
    + '.balcony' from dbo.tbl_FloorInfo group by BldgName
    set @_int = @_int +1
End
```

Result is:

```
    'BldgA.Floor_01.balcony'
    'BldgB.Floor_01.balcony'
    'BldgC.Floor_01.balcony'
     ..
     ..
    'BldgA.Floor_10.balcony'
    'BldgB.Floor_10.balcony'
    'BldgC.Floor_10.balcony'
     ..
     ..
     ..
    'BldgA.Floor_99.balcony'
    'BldgB.Floor_99.balcony'
    'BldgC.Floor_99.balcony'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you really want to go hard-core... ;-)

```
declare @int int
set @int = 1

declare @string varchar(max)
set @string = cast(@int as varchar(max))

declare @length int
set @length = len(@string)

declare @MAX int
set @MAX = 8

if @length < @MAX
begin
    declare @zeros varchar(8)
    set @zeros = ''

    declare @counter int
    set @counter = 0

    while (@counter < (@MAX - @length))
    begin
        set @zeros = @zeros + '0'
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end
    set @string = @zeros + @string
end
print @string
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Charles Bretana's answer is the simplest and fastest. A similar solution without using `STR` is:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REVERSE(
        CONVERT(CHAR(5 /*<= Target length*/)
                , REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @MyInt)))
     ), ' ', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
           
RIGHT((REPLICATE( '0', 4 ) + CAST([YOUR FIELD] AS VARCHAR(4))), 4) AS PaddedValue
    
FROM [YOUR TABLE] AS tt;
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?