# Convert date to YYYYMM format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to select value = `201301`

```
select getdate(), cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4))+cast(datepart(MONTH, getdate()) as varchar(2))
```

it returns `20131`.

What is the normal way to do this?

Comment: For more information check this link it list different date  format  sql server supports . https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(varchar, GetDate(),112),6)
```

Answer (score 115):

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(6), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Comment: Nice and simple. You could also drop unicode if you want: `SELECT CONVERT(varchar(6), GETDATE(), 112)`

Answer (score 52):

I know it is an old topic, but If your `SQL server` version is higher than 2012.

There is another simple option can choose, [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
SELECT FORMAT(GetDate(),'yyyyMM')
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/13149)

Comment: Among all the answers this is easy to understand by just looking at it and also can be modified easily if needed. +1 up

Comment: FYI, the first argument of `FORMAT` is a `date` type, so passing in a `varchar` or `nvarchar` will result in an error like, `Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.`

Comment: Also, no matter how long the other solutions take, FORMAT with take at least 26 times longer even when other solutions seem to be much more complex.

Answer (score 5):

A more efficient method, that uses integer math rather than strings/varchars, that will result in an int type rather than a string type is:

```
SELECT YYYYMM = (YEAR(GETDATE()) * 100) + MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Adds two zeros to the right side of the year and then adds the month to the added two zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this *is* the proper way to get what you want, unless you can use MS SQL 2014 (which finally enables custom format strings for date times).

To get `yyyymm` instead of `yyyym`, you can use this little trick:

```
select 
 right('0000' + cast(datepart(year, getdate()) as varchar(4)), 4)
 + right('00' + cast(datepart(month, getdate()) as varchar(2)), 2)
```

It's faster and more reliable than gettings parts of `convert(..., 112)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your date in many formats, for example :

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DATE_OF_DAY, 103) => 15/09/2016
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), DATE_OF_DAY, 3) => 15/09/16
```

Syntaxe :

```
CONVERT('TheTypeYouWant', 'TheDateToConvert', 'TheCodeForFormating' * )
```

- The code is an integer, here 3 is the third formating without century, if you want the century just change the code to 103.

**In your case**, i've just converted and restrict size by nvarchar(6) like this :

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(6), DATE_OF_DAY, 112) => 201609
```

See more at : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 1):

SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyyMM') as 'YYYYMM'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is simple format

```
convert(varchar(6),getdate(),112)
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a format modification for such type of value, in case u wanted to apply it for the whole column, u had to do the following:

SELECT TO_DATE(*variable-which-format-u-wanna-change*, 'YYYYMM')
FROM *table*;

However, I don't know how to use the output to add a column u_u

Comment: This is an old question that has several good answers. If you need more info please post a new question.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33350235)

Answer (score 0):

another simple option if you are satisfied with string format:

`concat(year(created_at), month(created_at))`

Answer (score -1):

It's month 1, so you're getting an expected value. you'll have to zeropad the month (1 -> 01), as per this answer: [How do I convert an int to a zero padded string in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309165/how-do-i-convert-an-int-to-a-zero-padded-string-in-t-sql)