# Pad A String With Leading Zeros for Specified Value Range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, padding

I've used the answer at  [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

to pad a column with leading zeros in my case it's two zeros and I'm using this:

```
RIGHT('0'+ISNULL(REPLACE(<columnName>, '"', ''),''),2)
```

Data ranges from 1 to 99 but also includes a value of  of 'UNK' for unknown which is truncated using this method.

Is there a way around this or should I be exploring a different solution as I'm dealing with text and numbers in the same column?

Cheers

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Second revision)
Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(<columnName>, '')) > 1
  THEN ISNULL(<columnName>, '')
  ELSE RIGHT ('00'+ ISNULL(<columnName>, ''), 2)
END
```

Sample input/output:

```
Input NULL  / Ouput '00'
Input 'UNK' / Ouput 'UNK'
Input '1'   / Ouput '01'
Input '99'  / Ouput '99'
```

Comment: Hi @bastos.sergio,  thank you for the answer - is it possible to handle both the UNK and single/double digit values in one statement? </br>  e.g. I want to convert 1 to '01' but keep 10 as '10' and UNK as 'UNK'.  so, in effect only add a zero to single digit numbers and leave everything else a lone.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you very much for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding comment added below @bastos.sergio's answer:

```
SELECT CASE isnumeric(Val) AND len(Val) = 1 THEN '0' + Val ELSE Val END
```