# Cast and Convert decimal to a zero in left in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, decimal

Let's say I have this SELECT statement

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT AS decimal(15,2) )
FROM MicrosoftDynamicsAx.dbo.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY G
```

And i get the result : -`372263.29`.So i want to get `-00000000372263.29`

How can i padding zero in the left ?
Thank in advance

Comment: `SELECT RIGHT('000000000000000000000'+cast (@Var AS NVARCHAR(100)),15)`

Comment: Please see my update of question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Search on "Leading zeros SQL" and you get dozens of results/answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key idea is that the output needs to be converted to a string to put `0`s in front.  If you don't like typing out long strings of 0s, you can use `str()` and `replace()`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(STR(G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT, 15, 2), ' ', '0')
FROM MicrosoftDynamicsAx.dbo.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY G;
```

EDIT:

To handle negative numbers . . .

```
SELECT TOP 1 (CASE WHEN G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT >= 0
                   THEN REPLACE(STR(G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT, 15, 2), ' ', '0')
                   THEN '-' + REPLACE(STR(ABS(G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT), 14, 2), ' ', '0')
              END)
FROM MicrosoftDynamicsAx.dbo.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY G;
```

Comment: I like this one , in the result i have `00000-372263.29` but  i should edit this to get `-00000372263.20`

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to store a numeric with the leading zeros, you would need to store it as a varchar. So when you want to have leading zeros, you can make a choice between:

- Storing values in the table as a numeric, then selecting the result as a varchar in order to display the leading zeros.
- Storing in the table as a varchar and then converting to a numeric whenever you want to do calculations.

In the above it looks like you have a numeric value in the table and want to pull out a fixed length string. Try:

```
SELECT TOP 1
     CASE 
         WHEN CAST(G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT AS decimal(15,2) >= 0 THEN
             RIGHT('000000000000000000000' + CAST(CAST(G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT AS decimal(15,2)) AS VARCHAR), 15)
         ELSE 
             '-' + RIGHT('000000000000000000000' + CAST(-1 * CAST(G.ACCOUNTINGCURRENCYAMOUNT AS decimal(15,2)) AS VARCHAR), 15)
    END
FROM 
     MicrosoftDynamicsAx.dbo.GENERALJOURNALACCOUNTENTRY G
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, also i get `00000-372263.29` i check way the second condition don't work

Comment: Yes now i get 000000372263.29 but i want -000000372263.29 i don't want change the  default vaule

Comment: Finally got it, try running that now? The other answer won't get you the right thing I don't think as it doesn't account for negative numbers.