# How to add zero in front of numeric value in T-SQL 2005 or 2008?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to export a table in fixed format way. When I have numeric field, I have to add leading zeroes.

I know with SQL Server 2012, I can use `FORMAT()`. How to do in SQL Server 2005?

For instance, in a column with number 18, with fixed length 10, I have to export:

```
0000000018
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert it to a `varchar` and use `right`.

```
select right(replicate('0', 10) + convert(varchar(10), YourNumberColumn), 10)
```

Comment: Hi Sean, I dislike this approach, 'cause if the input number is wider than your number (input = 1234 but your target width = 3 leads to a wrong result). Please have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the syntax

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(YourNumber,X),' ','0')
```

The X is the count of digits you want.

The advantage: Other approaches would cut the number and lead to wrong results, if the input is wider than the target length. This approach would create a chain of asterisc ("***")

Try this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Nmbr INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1),(12),(123),(1234);

SELECT REPLACE(STR(Nmbr,3),' ','0')
FROM @tbl
```

The result:

```
001
012
123
***
```

Answer (score 0):

```
right('00000000' + cast(YourValue as varchar(10)), 10)
```

Comment: You are missing a parentheses and this results in the inputted value (YourValue).

Comment: The approach with `RIGHT` will cut a number if your input is wider than the target width... You might have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this

```
replicate('0', 10 - Floor(LOG10(myField) + 1) + myField
```

Comment: What is the point of using LOG10 here? I am not saying it is incorrect, I want to understand the logic of why that is there.

Comment: Did you try this? I think you should cast the `myField` to string, otherwise you'll have numeric addition - which is not what you want. And there seems to be a flaw with numbers `<=10`...

Comment: The use of LOG10 it´s a way I like to use to fine how many digit por example LOG10(10) its 1 and LOG10(99) it´s les than 2 and LOG(100) is 2