# Adding / preserving leading zero while UPDATING a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am generating some pin numbers in increamental order using the script below and would like to include a leading zero..tried all sort of data type and seem to be losing the leading zero. Would appreciate some help here in UPDATING my table

```
WITH PIN_NO
AS
(
    SELECT 4310 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Firstname, Lastname ) NEW_PIN, *
    FROM Citizen
)

UPDATE PIN_NO
SET  PIN = CAST(NEW_PIN AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Table name: Citizen

```
Firstname       Lastname    PINOO      Address  Age    other columns....
John             Smith                20001     19
Andrew           Evans                363252    30
Bill             Towny                63322     67
Dame             Beaut                34222     34
```

Would like it to be

```
Firstname       Lastname    PINOO     Address  Age    other columns....
John             Smith      04310    20001      19
Andrew           Evans      04311    363252     30
Bill             Towny      04312    63322      67
Dame             Beaut      04313    34222      34
```

Any other relevant script will help.
Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `PIN00`?

Comment: the keyword is "padding", have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008 for an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prepend the number with enough zeroes and use [`RIGHT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx) to truncate it to the required length.

```
WITH PIN_NO
AS
(
    SELECT 4310 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Firstname, Lastname ) NEW_PIN, *
    FROM Citizen
)
UPDATE PIN_NO
SET  PIN = RIGHT('0000000000' + CAST(NEW_PIN AS VARCHAR(10)), 10)
```

Comment: works like charm...thanks V! The '10' at the end of the script, what is the purpose of that?

Comment: @optimisteve, The last `10`, the second parameter of the `RIGHT` function is the final length of the string that you want to get. For example, if you want your PIN to be 15 characters long, make the `'000...000'` string 15 chars long, and change both `10` to `15`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Replicate / RIGHT Function**:

Below example may help you:

```
DECLARE @tbl1 AS TABLE
(
    ITEM_NBR  VARCHAR(5),
    GRP_NBR VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('0001',221)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('0002',221)
INSERT INTO @tbl1 VALUES('0003',221)
```

**REPLICATE:**

```
SELECT 
    REPLICATE
    (
        '0',
        4-LEN(MAX(CAST(ITEM_NBR     as INT)))
    ) + 
    CAST( MAX(CAST(ITEM_NBR     as INT))+1 AS VARCHAR(5)) 
FROM @tbl1
GROUP BY GRP_NBR
```

**RIGHT:**

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT
    (
        (
            '00000000000'
            + 
            CAST( MAX(CAST(ITEM_NBR as INT))+1 AS VARCHAR(5))
        ) ,
        4
    ) 
FROM @tbl1
GROUP BY GRP_NBR
```

Comment: Hi and thanks Sandip. Whats the use / need of the DECLARE in the script.

Comment: I have define one temp table with Declare and give you example with data

Comment: thanks all. I thought the use of VARCHAR data type would normally preserve the leading zero

Comment: @Sandip...your script will only select the data. How about updating it?