# How to add leading padded zeros until 4 characters after that original number should come in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to generate running serial no like 0001, 0999, 1100, 19300 with leading padded zeros until four characters. I have written below query to generate that number.

```
Select Right(Power(10, 4) + 02, 4)

Select Right(Power(10, 4) + 102, 4)

Select Right(Power(10, 4) + 10002, 4)
```

**Actual Result:-**

0002

0102

0002

**Expected Result:-**

0002

0102

10002

In SQL Server 2012, there is FORMAT function available.

```
SELECT Format(1, '0002')

SELECT Format(1000, '0102')

SELECT Format(10000, '10002')
```

**Actual Output:-**

0002

0102

10002

Currently I am using SQL Server 2008. How can I achieve that padded left zeros until 4 characters length after that original number should come?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: @MahmutAliÖZKURAN, the linked question accepted answer does not provide my expected output.

Comment: How do you expect `10002` from `Select Right(Power(10, 4) + 10002, 4)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to work with the value's length:

```
Select CASE WHEN LEN([your_column]) > 4 THEN [your_column] ELSE Right(Power(10, 4) + [your_column], 4) END
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [**`REPLICATE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx):

```
DECLARE @i INT = 10
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN LEN(CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(4))) >=4 THEN CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(4))            
          ELSE REPLICATE('0', 4-LEN(CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(4)))) + CAST(10 AS VARCHAR(4))
       END
```