# SQL- using padding

Tags: sql

Need to sum(amounts) ,give it '0' padding of 10 character,replace the decimal with blank

**eg:**

```
Amount
34.56
45.12
12.23
```

Answer should look like `0000009191`

```
+ cast((SELECT sum([amount]) from #clm2) as CHAR(10))
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Which database engine? Do you really need to do it in the database and not in the presentation layer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+, consider **Format()**

```
Declare @Yourtable table (amount decimal(10,2))
Insert Into @Yourtable values
(34.56),
(45.12),
(12.23)

Select Format(sum(Amount*100),'0000000000')
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
0000009191
```

Comment: What do you mean with "2012+"? There is no such SQL standard

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

for padding

```
select '0000000000' + cast(fieldname as varchar)
```

and replace dots with blank space with padding

```
select replace('0000000000' + cast(fieldname as varchar),'.','')
```

get 10 characters from right

```
select right(replace('0000000000' + cast(fieldname as varchar),'.',''),10)
```