# Convert Int to text in SQL Server: how to display preceding zero '0'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an `int` column that I need to convert it into text. I tried to convert it into `varchar` but it did not display the preceding 0 when I tried to run the report thru batch file or export it to Excel,.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(a.Value AS VARCHAR(20)) AS Value
FROM 
    dbo.HPatientIdentifiers a
JOIN 
    HPatientVisit b ON a.Patient_oid = b.Patient_oid
WHERE 
    b.VisitTypeCode IN ('IP', 'EOP')
    AND a.IsVersioned = 0
    AND a.TYpe = 'MR'
    AND b.VisitEndDateTime >= DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY  
     a.Value
```

OUTPUT:

```
Value
------
4824
5663
10276
10459
```

Expected result:

```
Value
-------
004824
005663
010276
010459
```

Please help.

Comment: You just need one leading zero?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Yes, the value is 6 characters (int) but when I exported to excel it does not show me the preceding zeros.

Answer (score 1):

using `right()` and concatenating `0`s to the casted `varchar()` column:

```
SELECT right('000000'+CAST(a.Value as varchar(20)),6) AS Value

FROM dbo.HPatientIdentifiers a
JOIN HPatientVisit b
ON a.Patient_oid=b.Patient_oid

WHERE b.VisitTypeCode IN ('IP','EOP')
AND a.IsVersioned=0
AND a.TYpe='MR'
AND b.VisitEndDateTime >= DATEADD(dd,-1, GETDATE())

ORDER BY  a.Value
```