# SQL, Concatenate a character and leading 0 depending on the value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns Hour and Minute, both containing an integer. (There are other columns as well). Now, I want to create a view from this table and I need to combine these two columns' data into one column with a ':' symbol. For example, if a record has 8 for Hour, 10 for Minute, the combined column should contain 08:10. One digit numbers need to be followed by a leading 0, which initially does not exist in Hour and Minute columns.

I was successfully able to convert the integer to varchar and concatenate the numbers with ':' with the following SQL command

```
/* Combined Column name "Time" */
SELECT
  Cast([Hour] as varchar) + ':' + Cast([Minute] as varchar) As Time
FROM Table1
```

but I am not sure how I can add leading 0 to this only if the number is one digit. Can someone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: With example in question, to format time you should go with Gordon's answer, but for general trick how to add padding zeros check link in previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Other Approach :

```
SELECT
 (CASE WHEN LEN(Cast([Hour] as varchar))=1 THEN '0'+Cast([Hour] as varchar) ELSE Cast([Hour] as varchar)  END) + ':' +
   (CASE WHEN LEN(Cast([Minute] as varchar))=1 THEN '0'+Cast([Minute] as varchar) ELSE Cast([Minute] as varchar)  END)  As Time
FROM Table1
```

Hope its helps you ! :)

Comment: Thank you everyone, but I decided to go with this one. This was close to what I already had! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`timefromparts()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql) (SQL Server 2012+) to create a proper time value:

```
select timefromparts(hour, minute, 0, 0, 0)
```

You can then format this as a string, if that is what you really want to do:

```
select convert(varchar(5), timefromparts(hour, minute, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create scalar function to pad characters:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PadNumbersOnLeft (@NumberInput INT, @NoOfCharsToPad tinyint)
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ResultString VARCHAR(250)

    SET @ResultString = LTRIM(@NumberInput)

    IF(@NoOfCharsToPad > LEN(@ResultString))
        SET @ResultString = REPLICATE('0', @NoOfCharsToPad - LEN(@ResultString)) + @ResultString;

    RETURN @ResultString;
END;
```

And here is the example how to use this:

```
declare @hour int = 8
declare @minute int = 35

select 
[dbo].[PadNumbersOnLeft] (@hour, 2) + ':' + [dbo].[PadNumbersOnLeft] (@minute, 2)
```

You can replace your columns names with `@hour` and `@minute` variables.

Comment: This is really not a best idea, check first comment in question for much easier trick to do it.

Comment: I think in SQL 2008, its better to use scalar function like this, for re-usability purpose.

Comment: You mean ` SELECT RIGHT('000'+ISNULL(field,''),3)` ? Yes best one. agreed.