# How can I lead pad zeros in a Stream Analytics Query?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Within a Stream Analytics query, I'm trying to convert a date to a simple ISO 8601 date-only format, like so:

```
CONCAT(
    c.IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId, 
    '@', 
    CAST(DATEPART(year, EventProcessedUtcTime) as nvarchar(max)), 
    '-',
    CAST(DATEPART(month, EventProcessedUtcTime) as nvarchar(max)), 
    '-',
    CAST(DATEPART(day, EventProcessedUtcTime) as nvarchar(max))
) as partitionkey
```

This works alright, but it produces dates like so:

```
2017-3-5
```

I'd prefer that the dates be lead-zero-padded, like this:

```
2017-03-05
```

This is a [simple thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008) in T-Sql, but I don't see any of the tools necessary to make this or any of the other tricks work to be present in the [SA query language subset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/reference/stream-analytics-query-language-reference).

Anybody know a way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, I assume that you could use [Azure Stream Analytics JavaScript user-defined functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions).

For example, I just created a user-defined function named `dateFormat` as follows:

```html
function main(dateStr) {
    var date=new Date(dateStr);                                  
    var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString();        
    var dd  = date.getDate().toString(); 
    return date.getFullYear().toString() + '-' + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + '-' + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
SELECT UDF.dateFormat(EventProcessedUtcTime) FROM [YourInputAlias]
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid that, but I think that's probably the only way with as limited as the subset is.