# Generate Consult Sql with specific spaces, depending on the length of the field

Tags: c#, sql

I have a consult in sql where i select many fields, but I need that some fields have specific length, If the value of the field does not have the specified length, it must be filled with zeros or spaces

I filled this values in the server c# with a while for each one, but i need a best solution

The next table is a part of the records in database:

```
id  code

10  5987
11  34567
12  242
13  43244
```

And I paste a part of the code of server code

```
id=reader["id"]== DBNull.Value?string.Empty:Convert.ToString(reader["id"]);
                        while ( id.Length<15)
                        {
                            id= " " +id;
                        }
code =reader["code"]== DBNull.Value?string.Empty:Convert.ToString(reader["code"]);
                        while ( code.Length<10)
                        {
                            code = "0" +code;
                        }
```

I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Please add the SELECT query you are executing so we can help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Instead of your while loop use PadLeft, i.e. `id = id.PadLeft(15, ' ')` and `code = code.PadLeft(10, '0')`