# T-SQL Right Function default value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access, database-migration

I am working towards migrating an access **Right()** function onto SQL Server.

This is the Access **Right()** function:

```
Barcode: "ID" & (Right(String(8,"0") & [Job Number],8) & Right(String(6,"0") & 
[PART LIBARY HEADER_1]![PartID],6) & Right(String(6,"0") & [Part Assembly Link 
Table]![AssemblyLinkID],6))
```

What the above expression does, is that it dynamically creates a field to house a barcode that is always 22 characters in length. Now the values of these barcodes are determined by other columns. 
I am using the **Right()** method to gather the Rightmost: 8 chars of Job Number, 6 chars of PartID and 6 chars of AssemblyLinkID.

Now the problem I face is that whilst I can move these values onto T-SQL, I having difficulty setting the default value to be = 0.

For example the following input:

Job Number: **123456**

PartID: **9876**

AssemblyLinkID: **127**

Would need to return… ***ID00123456009876000127***

The **String()** function in access is handling the null values for me by appending with **0** but this method is not something available in SQL Server.

```
String(8,"0")
```

This is my SQL Code so far:

```
Concat('ID', RIGHT(STR(0, 8) & [Job Number],8)) AS Barcode,
```

**STR()** is not the function I am looking to use as it is not giving the same results as MS Access's **String()**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I would guess the function you are looking for, instead of `STRING`, is `REPLICATE`. For example, `REPLICATE('0',8)` would return `'00000000'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job you want:

```
declare @t table ([Job NUmber] int, PartID int, AssemblyLinkID int)
insert into @t ([Job NUmber], PartID, AssemblyLinkID) values(123456,9876,127)

select
    'ID' + 
    RIGHT('00000000' + CONVERT(varchar(8),[Job Number]),8) +
    RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6),PartID),6) +
    RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6),AssemblyLinkID),6)
from @t
```

You *can* use [`REPLICATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as an exact analogue for your `STRING` calls but since the string literals are shorter than the method call, I prefer them.

---

Not sure quite what your point was around `null`s, but if any of these columns may be `NULL`, then you may way to use `COALESCE` as well:

```
declare @t table ([Job NUmber] int, PartID int, AssemblyLinkID int)
insert into @t ([Job NUmber], PartID, AssemblyLinkID) values(123456,9876,127)
select
    'ID' + 
    RIGHT('00000000' + COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(8),[Job Number]),''),8) +
    RIGHT('000000' + COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(6),PartID),''),6) +
    RIGHT('000000' + COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(6),AssemblyLinkID),''),6)
from @t
```

(Here we'll get all zeros for a `NULL` value. If you want something different, substitute that into the empty string towards the end of each expression)

Comment: I'm not declaring the table variable, but the SELECT did exactly what I wanted it to do! Thanks! Are there any benefits for declaring the variable table as opposed to just using the select?

Comment: @RikuDas - it was just to make my example a complete runnable script. For future questions, you might consider providing your sample data in such a form - it's immediately copyable into a query window so that we can start writing a query and *test it*, without having any permanent effect on the database we're testing in.

Comment: I see that makes sense. I'm fairly new to SO but that is very useful to know. I'll bear it in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Right(String(8,"0") & [Job Number],8) =

```
RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + ISNULL([Job Number], ''), 8)
```