# Leading zero infront of row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this column called Week, that is a number. Instead of displaying it like week 1,2,3,4 etc i want to display with a 0 in front. I am working in Oracle Database.

The view is constructed as following:

```
Select "DATO","UGEDAG","WEEK","MÅNED","ÅR","KVARTAL","MÅNEDNUMMER","MÅNEDNUMMERTAL" 
from SC_DRIFT.EXCEL_DATO_UGE 
where DATO >= '2016-01-01'
```

Comment: Basically the same thing as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008) but translated in PL-SQL

Comment: For week 1 to 9 only, or for all weeks?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using lpad() function

```
Select "DATO","UGEDAG",LPAD("WEEK", 2, '0'),"MÅNED","ÅR","KVARTAL","MÅNEDNUMMER","MÅNEDNUMMERTAL" 
from SC_DRIFT.EXCEL_DATO_UGE 
where DATO >= '2016-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT
    "DATO",
    "UGEDAG",
     SUBSTR('0' || TO_CHAR(WEEK), -2, 2) AS "WEEK",
    "MÅNED",
    "ÅR",
    "KVARTAL",
    "MÅNEDNUMMER",
    "MÅNEDNUMMERTAL" 
FROM SC_DRIFT.EXCEL_DATO_UGE 
WHERE DATO >= '2016-01-01';
```

Comment: I suppose OP wants that leading 0 for week 1 to 9 only.

Comment: @jarlh Answer updated, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a  charm.

Comment: How do i solve this as jarlh said for only week 1 to 9

Comment: Reload your page, I fixed it.

Comment: Yes, I see. Thank you!