# Sql Query to add values to the existing values in a Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs-2008

Need to add "00" in-front of each row and the size of col1 is 3 i.e.,  (varchar(3))

I have data as below

```
col1
-----
1
02
003
4
05
```

I need to update the col1 values like prefix(001, 002, 003, 004, 005) as shown below.

```
col1
-----
001
002
003
004
005
```

I tried with SQL Server replicate function but I didn't get.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Pad a string with leading zeros so it's 3 characters long in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760900/pad-a-string-with-leading-zeros-so-its-3-characters-long-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 1):

This is really a presentation layer requirement.  I recommend just storing your `col1` values an integers, and then generating the zero padded number using something like:

```
SELECT RIGHT('000' + CAST(col1 AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) AS col1_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Could you please make this output with out using right() function?