# SQL String padding

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I there a way to pad String result in SQL server?

```
Select str from table_name where...
```

I want str to return with length of 13 with leading '0'.

For example:

1. if str = '12345678910' my where will return 13 positions: '0012345678910'
2. str = '12345' -> '000000012345'

In addition, after padding the result i need to query str 3,4 position.

Is there a way to do all of this in one query?

Comment: it's been asked before.....multiple times... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309165/how-do-i-convert-an-int-to-a-zero-padded-string-in-t-sql

Comment: The referenced answer shows implementation in T-SQL, is there an implementation is SQL?

Comment: TSQL is SQL.....you've tagged as sql server. it uses TSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using (T-SQL):

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',13)+ '12345',13)
```

Or (Oracle) :

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/lpad.php