# How to add varchar and integer in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to convert int to varchar and need to take care about one more    consideration.

For example:

1)My string length is always 10 characters.
    (i.e. "0000000001")

Whenever I generated a new id, it has to increment (i.e. "0000000002")
When it reaches the 10th string will be "0000000010", etc...
I have no idea how to implement this.
trying as a first step.

```
--Declared variable to increment count
declare @CTR INT
--@LIPRequestID is integer this is what i have to add to my 
declare @LIPRequestID int
select @LIPRequestID=0
declare @LIPRequestIDstring varchar(max)
select @ctr=0
WHILE @CTR<2
BEGIN
select @ctr=@ctr+1
select @LIPRequestID=@LIPRequestID+1

select @LIPRequestIDstring='00000000'+ CAST(@LIPRequestID AS VARCHAR(10)
print @LIPRequestIDstring
END
```

but it is throwing the following exception error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>       Incorrect syntax near '@LIPRequestIDstring'.

can anybody suggest where I am going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert an int to a zero padded string in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309165/how-do-i-convert-an-int-to-a-zero-padded-string-in-t-sql)

Comment: Why do you need a string that sort of behaves like a number? Why not just use a number and forget the padded 0's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenating the string literal `00000000` with the ID you should use `RIGHT`:

```
DECLARE @LIPRequestIDstring varchar(10);
DECLARE @nextLIPRequestID int;
SET @nextLIPRequestID = (SELECT MAX(LIPRequestID) FROM dbo.TableName) + 1;
SET @LIPRequestIDstring = RIGHT('0000000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@nextLIPRequestID),10)
```

Comment: The script will not work for a single digit integer. 
The last line of the script should have 9 zeros instead of 8
`SET @LIPRequestIDstring = RIGHT('000000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@nextLIPRequestID),10)`
Apart from that the script works like a charm.

Comment: there are no tables yet, number should genarate on the fly and need to store this in the table

Comment: @Pankaj: i guess 10 digits instead of 8 because "always my string length is 10 characters".

Comment: @chaithanyakishore: how do you want to calculate the next number if you don't store the last? Or do you want to extract it from the last/maximum number? You have to use `CONVERT` to get an `int` from the varchar number like here: `CONVERT(int, (SELECT MAX(LIPRequestID) FROM dbo.TableName))`. Then add `1` and you have the new number.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: Actually i have to create dummy data into the tables, for that there is a coloumn with auto genarated and it will save. I am trying to create this value and have to use this as reference key in other tables

Answer (score 0):

`Parenthesis` missing in `cast` function, other things looks fine

```
select @LIPRequestIDstring='00000000'+ CAST(@LIPRequestID AS VARCHAR(10))--here
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
CAST(@LIPRequestID AS VARCHAR(10)
```

use

```
CAST(@LIPRequestID AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Comment: yes,correct this silly mistake, but 2nd issue, but while incrementing the number to 10 my string is becoming 11 characters, if string length is more than 10 characters have to remove the first  '0'. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **RIGHT** function, we can use **REPLACE** function. This will help you to implement your two requirements. The length of the ID also can be passed as parameter **@IDLength**.

```
DECLARE @CTR INT = 0
DECLARE @LIPRequestID INT = 0

DECLARE @IDLength INT = 8

DECLARE @LIPRequestIDstring VARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE (@CTR < 12)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CTR += 1
        SELECT @LIPRequestID += 1
        PRINT  REPLACE(STR(@LIPRequestID, @IDLength), SPACE(1), '0')
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Right function really make sence, thanks to sql and stackoverflow.

declare @LIPRequestIDstring varchar(max)
select @LIPRequestID=@LIPRequestID+1
select @LIPRequestIDstring=RIGHT('0000000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@LIPRequestID),10)